# What is the concept of Remoting, Spring Remoting?

Tags: spring, remoting, spring-remoting

I am learning Spring Framework, and many places I came across "Spring Remoting". As I can guess "Spring Remoting" would be Spring's support for `Remoting`.

My doubt is what is `Remoting`?  And is `Spring Remoting` different from normal `Remoting`.

Any explanation in simple words would be of great help.

Comment: It means: calling methods on objects that are running in a different JVM (on the same machine, or on another machine) than the JVM that your program is running in. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#remoting).

Comment: @Jesper: thanks for your reply. In that case EJB, RMI can be qualified as `Remoting`, so `Web Services`? What is so special about `Spring Remoting`? Any further pointer if you can point, would be of great help.

Comment: Web services can also be seen as a kind of [remote procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (<= click link for details on Wikipedia). "Spring remoting" is just Spring's implementation for doing remote procedure calls, using whatever protocol you want (RMI, or something else).